# Filter records based on Time using Dataview Rowfilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, dataview, rowfilter

Is it possible to get records between a Timespan from a DataTable using the RowFilter property of the Defaultview that belongs to the table.

**Purpose:**
I would like to check if `Current Time(DateTime.Now.ToString())` falls withing the Time defined in the Database table schema. Schema of the table is defined below

```
                          `Name | From | To | JoinedOn |`
```

where From To are datetime columns on the database table. I would like to compare only time values from the datetime columns rather than the dates also. I Tried below but doesn't yield the result.
`dt_Temp.DefaultView.RowFilter = "From < '"+ DateTime.Now.ToString()+"' AND To >'"+ DateTime.Now.ToString()+"'";` anyone have any idea?

**Specs:**

.Net Framework 2.0

ViSual studio 2005

Sql server express 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would skip the DefaultView and write a Linq query agains the DataTable instead

```
var time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
var q = 
  from row in dt_Temp.AsEnumerable();
  where row.Field<DateTime>("From").TimeOfDay < time && row.Field<DateTime>("To").TimeOfDay  > time
  select row;
```

**Edit**
Here is a 2.0 compatible function of that query

```
private static IEnumerable<DataRow> GetRows(DataTable dt_Temp)
{
    TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt_Temp.Rows)
        if(((DateTime)row["From"]).TimeOfDay < time && ((DateTime)row["To"]).TimeOfDay > time)
            yield return row;
}
```

Comment: @Magnus sorry i forgot to specify my framework version. I use 2.0 for the application. It is client needs So Linq out of the way

Comment: @Magnus Neatly written and IEnumurable works the charm but out of curiosity what was wrong with the dataview and rowfilter isn't it efficient enough?

Comment: Not sure how I would write such a filter just to compare the Time parts. Also I like working with strongly typed objects.

Comment: @Magnus accepted as answer and does the method need to be static is it mandate thing? doesn't the method need to return rows to be enumerable rather than DataRow

Comment: Does not need to be static. If you want to use the `yield return` than the return type must be IEnumerable<DataRow> (a collection of rows)

Comment: `yield return` will convert the whole function into an enumerator, thats why `yield return DataRow` works instead of example `return List<DataRow>`

Answer (score 0):

Astonished by my own intelligence :) the below rowfilter answer my query

**`"From <= #" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "# AND To >#" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "#";`**